# Azure Firewall across multiple regions?

Tags: azure

I have a question on Azure firewall. We have servers in azure Indian region behind azure firewall. We are now deploying servers also in azure Europe region. Do I need to deploy Azure firewall in Europe or I can use the one from India?

Answer (score 0):

They are separate vnets in differents regions, so yes you would. It is hard to suggest a solution without knowing your objective though.

If they were in the same region, you could have setup multiple vnets and connected them via peering and then setup routes to push all connecting vnets to the core one which the firewall is setup on so all their traffic is routed via it (like a hub-and-spoke model). Peering is supported region to region, but I would not suggest that, due to inconsistencies in the service, not to mention the latency.

Although, do think about whether you really need a firewall. I secure/connect environments by simply creating solid NSG's and utilising the AzureVPN to create IPsec tunnels.

Many ways to achieve the same result, just depends on your environments complexities. Use this article for further information https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-faq